# How do you loop thru a list of worksheets using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, loops, xlsxwriter

How can you pre-prend a list of names to the example below?  I want to call a method many time but the first part will change from ws1, ws2, ws3,...This method is from a module called "xlsxwriter" used to write rows of data inside an excel worksheet.

For example, first loop should create:

ws1.write(1, 0, 'Platform', format)

```
ws_names = ['ws1', 'ws2', 'ws3']

for entry in ws_names:

    '%s'.write (1, 0, 'Platform', format)  % entry
```

I am getting this error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I tried, entry.write (1, 0, ...    but I get the same error.

Comment: why not use `entry.write(1, 0, 'Platform', format)` ?

Comment: What is the `ws11 and what is the expected output?

Comment: Your error is telling you that strings don't have a `write()` method, What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ IanAuld, @ myaut:   the expected output is ws1.write(1,0,'Platform', format) which will write an row in an excel worksheet.   This is from a module called: xlxswrite.   I have a dozen worksheets or more, and trying to reduce the # of ws[1,2,3,...].write statements.   I don't believe this question has been answered -- the referenced link does not help me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This isn't a duplicate but it is an XY problem.

Comment: @Jim_Durkin: An easier way to do what you want to do is to use the XlsxWriter `worksheet()` method like this `for worksheet in workbook.worksheets(): worksheet.write(1, 0, 'Platform', format)`. See the docs on [`worksheets()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#workbook-worksheets).